# Pyro - Preventing NameServer from raising socket.error Address already in use

Tags: python, sockets, pyro

I'm trying to harden a Pyro application for production. I am running into the following issue with the Name Server.

If the Name Server is turned off and rapidly turned back on, there seems to be a 50% chance that it will throw the following error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

This can be tested by running the Name Server in a window (`pyro4-ns`), hitting CTRL+C, and running it again. Sometimes I can do this 10 times in a row with no problem, but the next 10 times will raise the `socket.error`. I've found that it takes about 30 seconds for the Name Server to release the socket when I encounter this error.

I am using `supervisord` to control Pyro. I've found the following configuration ameliorates some of the problems. Notably, the `startretries=50` will always take longer than the 30 seconds or so it takes the NameServer to release the socket. This way, if the process was to die for some reason, `supervisord` can start it without failing.

```
[program:pyro-ns]
command=pyro4-ns
priority=1
startretries=50
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

However, if during the middle of my client execution the Name Server dies, it would take over 30 seconds to reconnect to the NameServer because of this issue. I am using a Pyro client in a webserver for REST tasks, so this delay is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Irman for the [answer](https://github.com/irmen/Pyro4/issues/100).

If the PYRO_SOCK_REUSE environment is set to True, this error doesn't happen,  as it sets SO_REUSEADDR on the socket.

Either:

```
export PYRO_SOCK_REUSE=True
pyro4-ns
```

Or in Supervisor's config:

```
[program:pyro-ns]
environment = PYRO_SOCK_REUSE="True"
command=pyro4-ns
```